# Should this answer be flagged?

Tags: discussion, answers, not-an-answer

Should [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32610361/4151918) be flagged?

[It showed up in the Suggested Edits queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9554685), and I wasn't sure how to handle it.

It starts out with a question for the OP, then suggests a possible reason, implying that the OP should try again to see if the issue is fixed.

My first instinct was to flag it as "not an answer," but that might be declined, as it may end up being the answer if the solved known issue turns out to resolve the question.

Should I be flagging it as "in need of moderator attention," and ask them to determine whether it should become a comment, or remain an answer?  *Perhaps that would be declined, also?*

Comment: I would (and just did) flag as Not An Answer.

Comment: The answer's gone now.

Comment: I've converted it to a comment (I was in a generous mood).

Comment: The amusing part was where the answerer asked OP to accept his answer-comment even though it appeared unrelated to how OP solved their own issue.